# Making a decimal a variable

Tags: c++

So I have a type of code that tells me the number of boxes and packages needed. So for an instances E = number of engines and B = boxes and P =packages. Lets say I need 67 engines, I have B = E(67)/24 which should give me 2.7 because 67/24. I have to have the computer say 2 boxes and 7 engines, but I dont know how to do that.

Thanks!

```
    // Include Section
     #include <iostream>
     #include <iomanip>
     #include <cstdlib>
     using namespace std;

     // Main Program
     int main( )
     {
        int E;     // number of engines needed
        double CB; // The cost of the boxes containing 24 engines
        double CP; // The cost of the packages containing 3 engines
        int B;     // The number of boxes needed to get the amount                  
        int P;     // The number of packages needed to get the amount of engines
        double C;  // The total cost of all the engines desired.

    // Output Identification
     system("CLS");
     cout << "Take Home #5 by Yousef Saqer - "
         << "Calculate Engine Purchase\n\n";

    cout << " Enter the number of engines needed: ";
    cin >> E;
    cout << " Enter the cost of a box of 24 engines: ";
    cin >> CB;
    cout << " Enter the cost of a package of 3 engines: ";
    cin  >> CP;



   if(E < 24)
   {
    B = E / 24;
    P = E / 3;
    C = CB * B + CP * P;

    if(E > 3)
    {
        P++;
        cout << " You will need to purchase " << P 
        << " packages of engines at a total cost of $"<< C << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << " You will need to purchase " << 1
        << " package of engines at a total cost of $"<< CP << endl;
    }


   }

   else
   {
    B = E / 24;
    P = E/24.0;
    C = CB * B + CP * P;

    if( B != 1)
    {
        cout << " You will need to purchase " << B << " boxes and "
         << P << " packages of engines at a total cost of $"<< C<< endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << " You will need to purchase " << B << " box and " 
        << P << " packages of engines at a total of $" << C << endl;
    }

}
cout << "\n\nEnd Program.\n";

cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `67/24` yields `2` because of integer division. `67.0/24.0` would give you a floating point result.

Comment: First of all, 67/24 means you need 2 boxes and 19 engines. Second, If you don't know how to convert 2.7 to 2 and 7, you have some serious learning to do.

Comment: You should add 0.5 to the result then convert to an integer.  You want to round up, unless you can have 0.7 boxes assigned to an engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main (){
    double param, fractpart, intpart;

    param = 2.7;
    fractpart = modf (param , &intpart);

    return 0;
}
```

This way `param=2` and `intpart=0.7`

Here is the whole code
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/